# what is the type of LetterP?

Tags: haskell

I have some questions about the following program.

```
import Data.List(nub) 
import qualified Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ as PP
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ(Doc,text,int,(<>),(<+>),($+$),render)

data Prop a = 
     LetterP a
   | AndP (Prop a) (Prop a)
 deriving Eq

class PPLetter a where
  ppLetter :: a -> Doc

instance PPLetter Int where
  ppLetter a = text ("p"++show a)

instance PPLetter Char where
  ppLetter = PP.char

instance PPLetter a => PPLetter [a] where
  ppLetter = PP.hcat . (map ppLetter)

class PP a where
  pp :: a -> Doc

instance PP Bool where
  pp True = text "True"
  pp False = text "False"

parens n (term@(LetterP _)) = pp term

instance PPLetter a => PP(Prop a) where   
  pp (LetterP a) = ppLetter a
  pp (AndP x y) = PP.sep [ parens 4 x, text "/\\", parens 4 y]

instance PPLetter a => Show (Prop a) where
  show x = render (pp x)

main = do
    let p = LetterP 1
    print p
```

1. I can't see a definition of `LetterP`, so I assume it is from an imported package. Is that correct?
2. When I compile it, I get an error:

   ```
   ho8.hs:19:12: parse error on input `='
   Failed, modules loaded: none.
   ```

   why do I get this error, and how do I solve it? I tried to print `LetterP` but it didn't
   work.
3. What does `parens n (term@(LetterP _)) = pp term` mean, what do `parens` do and what is `term@`? Why is there no definition of `term`?
4. After removing `{}`, I get the following error. Why?

   ```
   ho8.hs:43:9:
       Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
         (PPLetter a0) arising from a use of `print' at ho8.hs:43:9-13
         (Num a0) arising from the literal `1' at ho8.hs:42:25
       Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
       In the expression: print p
       In the expression:
         do { let p = LetterP 1;
              print p }
       In an equation for `main':
           main
             = do { let p = ...;
                    print p }
   Failed, modules loaded: none.
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LetterP` is a data constructor for the type `Prop`. It is defined in the following part of your code:

```
data Prop a = 
     LetterP a
   | AndP (Prop a) (Prop a)
 deriving Eq
```

It can not be printed because it does not derive `Show` and there is also no manual instance for `Show (Prop a)` in your code. However the error you posted is a syntax error and not related to that.

The `(var@pattern)` syntax is used to give a name to the value matched by the pattern. So `parens n (term@(LetterP _)) = pp term` matches if the second argument is a value using the constructor `LetterP` and assigns that value to the argument `term`.

`AndP` like `LetterP` is a constructor for the type `Prop`.

Comment: what do these constructor do ?

Comment: @MFLDSH: It constructs value of type `Prop`. For more information see [the Wikipedia article on Algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Answer (score 1):

`LetterP` is not a type, it's a constructor of type `Prop`, see line 8.

The pattern syntax

```
name@pattern
```

binds name to the value if the pattern matches. Thus in your case, `term` is bound to the 2nd argument of function `parens` and then it is checked if this value was constructed with `LetterP`.

The error you get is because you can't write equations inside do { } blocks. You must prepend them with let.

Change it like so

```
 main = do
    let p = LetterP 1
    print p
```

Comment: It constructs a value of type `Prop`. It can be seen as a function that takes a value of any type `a` and returns a value of type `Prop a`.

Comment: I wonder how you could miss it, it's defined on line 8 of your code. Or is that not your code?